# Union-all postgresql select clauses preserving order

Tags: postgresql, large-data, olap

Having complex SQL query to RDBMS Postgresql which consists of multiple nested UNION ALL-like nested queries, something like this:

```
(
  (
     (<QUERY 1-1-1> UNION ALL <QUERY 1-1-2>) UNION ALL
     (<QUERY 1-1-3> UNION ALL <QUERY 1-1-4>) UNION ALL
     ...
  ) UNION ALL
  (
     (<QUERY 1-2-1> UNION ALL <QUERY 1-2-2>) UNION ALL
     (<QUERY 1-2-3> UNION ALL <QUERY 1-2-4>) UNION ALL
     ...
  ) UNION ALL
  ...
) UNION ALL
(
  (
     (<QUERY 2-1-1> UNION ALL <QUERY 2-1-2>) UNION ALL
     (<QUERY 2-1-3> UNION ALL <QUERY 2-1-4>) UNION ALL
     ...
  ) UNION ALL
  (
     (<QUERY 2-2-1> UNION ALL <QUERY 2-2-2>) UNION ALL
     (<QUERY 2-2-3> UNION ALL <QUERY 2-2-4>) UNION ALL
     ...
  ) UNION ALL
  ...
) UNION ALL
(
  ...
)
```

Each <QUERY i-th> is relatively lightweight query which produces about 100K-1M rows and can be sorted in-memory without significant performance impact.

Result query is consists of tens thousands multi-level nested UNION ALL queries in strict conventional order, like traversing tree in depth, so result query is several billion rows dataset.

So question is: since SQL does not guarantee order of UNION ALL statement, outer query should contain ORDER BY clause, but server hardware cannot perform sorting of billon rows in required time.

However, order of united queries is strict determined, and should be: <QUERY 1-1-1>, <QUERY 1-1-2> and so on, sorted hierarchically, so in fact sorting of outer query is redundant, since dataset is **already** sorted by sql query structure.

It's necessary to force Postgres to preserve order of nested UNION ALL statements. How to do it? Any plugins, extensions and even dirty hacks are welcome.

Please avoid of answers and comments mention XY-like problem - question is formulated as-is in research manner. Structure of database and dataset cannot be changed by conditions of question. Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to do that, and I doubt that you can get reasonable performance with a query like that. It is no use to insist on a solution within your narrow problem description, you'll have to cast the net wider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - allocate the queries' results into a temporary table.
Here it is step by step:

- Create a temporary table ex. `the_temp_table` like the the record type of `<QUERY 1-1-1>`

```sql
create temporary table the_temp_table as <QUERY 1-1-1> limit 0;
```

- Add an auto-increment primary key column `extra_id` to `the_temp_table`

```sql
alter table the_temp_table add column extra_id serial primary key not null;
```

- Then run all your queries one by one in the right order

```sql
insert into the_temp_table <QUERY 1-1-1>; insert into the_temp_table <QUERY 1-1-2>;
insert into the_temp_table <QUERY 1-1-3>; insert into the_temp_table <QUERY 1-1-4>;

insert into the_temp_table <QUERY 1-2-1>; insert into the_temp_table <QUERY 1-2-2>;
insert into the_temp_table <QUERY 1-2-3>; insert into the_temp_table <QUERY 1-2-4>;

-- continue
```

- Finally

```sql
select <fields list w/o extra_id> from the_temp_table order by extra_id;

-- no sorting is taking place here
```

Effectively thus you will be emulating `UNION ALL` in a controlled manner with an insignificant performance penalty.

Comment: Brilliant! Solution can run in single transaction to ensure disposure of temporary table after loading datum from it.    

Also interesting, if maximum rows count from query <QUERY i-th> is strictly denominated, can <QUERY i-th> queries be run concurrently?    

For instance, if maximum rows count is N, then <QUERY 1-1-1> can write in rows 0..N-1, <QUERY 1-1-2> can write in rows N...2*N-1 and so on.     

Some rows in the_temp_table will remain empty since N is maximum, not exact size of <QUERY i-th>, but these rows can be ignored on final reading.

Comment: I think that you can do the above. Here is the rough idea. First remove the auto-increment (i.e. `serial` becomes `bigint`) from `extra_id`. Then modify your queries -   add an extra select expression to each of them like this `N * <a big number> + row_number() over () as extra_id`. `N` is the query ordinal number. So each individual query will be generating its own range of `extra_id` values, run concurrently and still be ordered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways of looking at this:

- The safest alternative is be to declare an id column using SERIAL or BIGSERIAL, which will be ordered and indexed. As the records are already ordered there will be a minimal effect on query speed and you will be sure that there are no errors in the ordering.
- If the order is not critical, and you don't modify the data **at all** it will **probably** be fetched in the same order as you entered it. There is no guarantee. How important is the order to your application?

Comment: Ordering of datum is critical important for application. My thoughts was using PLV8 with set returning function https://plv8.github.io/#set-returning-function-calls . In that case it's possible to perform queries <QUERY i-th> one-by-one and return rows respectively. Also it's seems that such solution will not overuse RAM since result of each <QUERY i-th> will be delivered to client before executing next <QUERY (i+1)-th>